# Traversing a robot in a prespecified path

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
Last day i was trying out an experiment to traverse a robot in a pre specified path (say a mathematical curve). To keep thing simple at the beginning I choose a straight path. I made a learning_joy package and added the following code in the `learning_joy/src/turtle_teleop_joy.cpp`:

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "turtlesim/Velocity.h"
#include "geometry_msgs/Twist.h"

class TeleopTurtle
{
public:
    TeleopTurtle();

    void move_robot();

    ros::NodeHandle nh_;

    ros::Publisher vel_pub_;
};


TeleopTurtle::TeleopTurtle()
{
    vel_pub_ = nh_.advertise<geometry_msgs::Twist>("base_controller/command",1);

    move_robot();
}

void TeleopTurtle::move_robot()
{
    geometry_msgs::Twist cmdvel;

    int i = 0;
    while(i < 100) //continue publishing the message
    {
        cmdvel.angular.z = 0;
        cmdvel.linear.x = 2;
        vel_pub_.publish(cmdvel);
        i++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "teleop_turtle");

    TeleopTurtle teleop_turtle;

    ros::spin();
}
```

the steps i followed after that are:

```
$ roscore

$ roscd stage
./bin/stageros world/willow-erratic.world
$ rosmake learning_joy

$ rosrun learning_joy turtle_teleop_joy
```

This does not give any errors but the robot does not move. `rxgraph` shows that the node is running. Can you please tell me the reason as to why this does not work ?
Regards!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/45020/traversing-a-robot-in-a-prespecified-path/) by [koushik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3302/koushik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-10-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2012-10-02**:
do you see the topic you publish (base_controller/command) when you type in "rostopic list". If so, have you tried "rostopic echo base_controller/command" to see that you can publish the messages correctly?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2012-10-03**:
@koushik just FYI, if you put four spaces in front of each line of your C code, it will end up formatted as C code in your post.  This makes it much easier for others to read, meaning they will often be more likely to help.

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2012-10-04**:
@jarvis You can also do 

```
 ..code..
```

 which is way easier for big snippets.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2012-10-04**:
@felix k  haha yeah good point!  I usually paste them in from emacs, and just use string-insert-rectangle to accomplish the 4 spaces.  But you are definitely right, the tags are much easier

**Comment by [aarontan](https://answers.ros.org/users/35174/aarontan/) on 2018-06-16**:
hello, have you found the complete code that would be able to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The robot is only going to move if the twist commands are published to the proper topic (`/cmd_vel` if memory serves right)...

So you will have to remap `/cmd_vel` (or what ever the topic is called) to `/base_controller/command`. (Take a look [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Nodes#Command-line_Remapping_Arguments))

To check this as @yygyt has indicated use rostopic.

---

Originally posted by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) with karma: 2022 on 2012-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0